# Combine 2d density plot with ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a dataframe with 20 dates, and for each date, 50 values. I am trying to plot a 2d density plot of these values, that remains inside the minimum-maximum ribbon. An exemple of what I want is there :

[image]

I know how to have a 2d density plot, as well as a ribbon, but not to connect both together. This is my attempt :

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
require(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(248)

##Create reproducible example
Chass <- data.frame(nb=rep(1:50, 10), x=rep(1:10, each=50), val=c(sample(seq(7,9,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(17,19,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(10,12,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(7,10,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(6,18,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(5,11,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(6,13,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(2,7,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(4,8,0.1), size=50, replace = T),
                                                                  sample(seq(3,16,0.1), size=50, replace = T)))

##Compute statistics for the ribbon
Chass_stats <- summarise(group_by(Chass, x), min=min(val, na.rm=T), mean=mean(val, na.rm=T), max=max(val, na.rm=T))

## Get both
p1 <- ggplot(Chass, aes(x=x, y=val))
p1 <- (p1
       + theme_bw()
       + ggtitle("Chass")
       + geom_density_2d_filled(aes(fill = ..level..), contour_var = "ndensity", bins = 10)
       + geom_line(data=Chass_stats, aes(y=mean), color="black")
       + geom_line(data=Chass_stats, aes(y=min), color="black", linetype="dashed")
       + geom_line(data=Chass_stats, aes(y=max), color="black", linetype="dashed")
       + scale_fill_manual(name = "% ", values=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "YlOrBr"))(10))
       + ylab("Value")
       + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()))

p1
```

which gives

[image]

The density plot does not respect the temporal coherence needed and goes outside of the boundaries... does someone can help with that ?

Thanks !

Comment: In short: I don't think this is possible (but very interested to be proven wrong). Slightly longer: You *could* try and calculate isobands manually (e.g. using [`isoband`](https://wilkelab.org/isoband/) which needs z data on a regularly spaced grid), store the polygons and then mask the polygon regions based on the ribbon band bounds before plotting. This may or may not work. Either way it sounds fairly messy.

Comment: What would your ideal result look like, for the sample dataset you provided?